# Tap Event Fired Twice JQuery Mobile on iPhone 4 IOS 7.1

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, mobile-safari

In a very simple page, when tapping on button and re-tapping anywhere else the event is fired again. 
JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/lajabe/1/
IOS 7.1 iPhone 4

Comment: If you replace alert with console.log, it fires once.

Comment: The only way so far that iv'e been able to fix that is by using cookies. I knew about the alert but not console.log (cheers Omar). But the cookies way basically sets a flag between a click or tap or taphold or swipe, and by setting a timeout function it will disable anything but what you are intending to do, so they don't fire other functions. I found Sometimes prevent/stoppropagate etc dont work well at times. Cookies was the only solution. Its strange but it works

Comment: @Omar http://jsbin.com/lajabe/1/ here is an updated JS Bin without alert and the same issue occured